# Differential Equations Applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An initial amount $\alpha$ of a tracer (such as a dye or a radioactive isotope) is injected into Compartment 1 of the two-compartment system shown in the Figure. At time $t > 0$, let $x_1 (t)$ and $x_2 (t)$ denote the amount of tracer in Compartment 1 and Compartment 2, respectively. Thus under the conditions stated, $x_1 (0) = \alpha$ and $x_2
(0) = 0$. The amounts are related to the corresponding concentrations $\rho_1 (t)$ and $\rho_2 (t)$ by the equations
$x_1 = \rho_1 V_1$ and $x_2 = \rho_2 V_2$ (i)
where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the constant respective volumes of the compartments. The differential equations that describe the
exchange of tracer between the compartments (using the relations in (i),) are

dx1/dt = −L21x1 + L12x2
dx2/dt = L21x1 − L12x2

where L21 = k21 / V1 is the fractional turnover rate of Compartment 1 with respect
to 2 and L12 = k12 / V2 is the fractional turnover rate of Compartment 2 with
respect to 1. Solve the system of differential equations using elimination when
L21 = 2/25, L12 = 1/50 and α = 25.

My solution:
I've tried solving and found x2 = c1+c2e^(-1/10)t after using initial conditions we get x2 = 96(1-e^(-1/10t)) and x1 = 1/4(96-e^(-1/10t))+5/4e^(-1/10t) verify my solution and let me know how to improve it.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @SeanRoberson sorry the comment just got messed up  x(t) = α/(L21+L12) $ \begin{pmatrix}L12 \\ L21\end{pmatrix} $ + L21α/(L21+L12) $ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} $ e^-(L21+L12)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Its a modified version of problem#13 Ex#6.1 Book (Differential Equations: An Introduction to Modern Methods and Applications
By James R. Brannan, William E. Boyce)

Comment: @SeanRoberson I've tried solving and found complementary solution x2 = c1+c2e^(-1/10)t after using initial conditions we get x2 = 96(1-e^(-1/10t)) and x1 = 1/4(96-e^(-1/10t))+5/4e^(-1/10t) verify my solution and let me know how to improve it.